# More than one construction matches argument list

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

I tried to compile it with VS2010

```
long long min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
unsigned long long max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();


std::bitset<64> minimal(min);//here I'm getting the error  
cout << "minimal: " << minimal;
```

```
error:  
error C2668: 'std::bitset<_Bits>::bitset' : ambiguous call to overloaded function  
1>          with  
1>          [  
1>              _Bits=64  
1>          ]  
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\bitset(136): could   be 'std::bitset<_Bits>::bitset(_ULonglong)'  
1>          with  
1>          [  
1>              _Bits=64  
1>          ]  
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\bitset(127):   or       'std::bitset<_Bits>::bitset(int)' 
1>          with  
1>          [  
1>              _Bits=64  
1>          ]    
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(__int64)'
```

Why? Obviously this argument is of a long long type and the constructor should be used for this type. I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see `long long` as one of the options you're given in that list. I only see:

- _ULonglong
- int
- _int64

Why don't you cast `min` to `unsigned long long` and see if that fixes it. Or better yet, *use* the unsigned type - are you ever likely to *have* a bitset with a negative number of elements? :-)

Comment: yes, they do not provide ctor for this type (bit strange). Anyway, their bit representations are different yet when comparing them (min <= max) I'm getting return false, how's that possible?

Comment: @smallB, that should be a _different_ question (and with the offending code added somewhere) since you'll get more exposure (and a better class of answer) that way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in VC2010 and it has been fixed in VC2011.

Here is the **[Bug Report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532897/problems-constructing-a-bitset-from-an-unsigned-long-in-the-vc-rc)** note the comments there.

Comment: thanks, it does compile with VC11, any chance of telling me why comparison of min <= max fails to be correct? Even if applying UAC the bit pattern is different for those values, so I really cannot see a reason for that.